# Check if there will be graph represented by incidence matrix, hamilton? Draw the graph.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

My task is:
"Check if there will be graph represented by incidence matrix and is it hamilton graph? Draw the graph."

[Matix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpkFw.png)

$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&0&1}
$$

I have no idea how to start as it is not an adjacency matrix (because it doesn't have a symmetrical amount of rows and columns), it is not an incidence matrix (as it has 3 nodes for a branch).

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Your task, as you have written it, seems to imply that the matrix is an incidence matrix. However, as you have said, this is clearly not the case. Are you sure that you interpreted the task correctly?

Comment: Hello. First I thought there is some mistake in the task because from files given to me to study there was no similar example to show how to that kind of task. But the task I have given here is rewrited by me from the task file from instructor. I send the task here because I am not sure if I miss something or the task is just wrong.